# How to convert a range of cells from Dec to Hex in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm just wondering how I would go about converting a range of cells from decimal to hex without making the spreadsheet huge and very slow. I would also like to use VBA for it as it would be used for analysis.

The way I have thought about doing this would be to convert the cells using the `DEC2HEX` formula and then hiding all the decimal cells but obviously this makes the spreadsheet quite large. If there is a way to just convert the values and replace those cells with the hex value, it would be very helpful.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want only to display the values in hexadecimal format without changing them to text, you can't do that. You will have to use Dec2Hex, then copy as value and paste over the old values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution ->

```
Sub convertRangeToHex() 
Dim r As Range 
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Application.Selection 'define your range

For Each r In myRange
    If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then
        r.Value = "0x" & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(r.Value)
    End If 
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: @MattGriffin no problem, had time to kill ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dec2Hex` in VBA through the `WorksheetFunction` class:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ConvertToHex Sheet1.Range("A1:A15")

End Sub

Sub ConvertToHex(rngData)

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rngData
        rngCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(rngCell.Value)
        rngCell.NumberFormat = "@" '<-- tidies formatting of hex
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your answer. I got an 'Unable to get Dec2Hex property of Worksheet Function' error when running this code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MattGriffin - I am surprised - just ran it again and works fine my end. The code is very similar to Han Soalone's. What range are you passing to the Sub? I presented this in a Sub as I thought you may use it in a bunch of different places and therefore would want to pass in different ranges on different occasions. Instead of `Sheet1.Range("A1:A15") you can use `Application.Selection` or whatever works for you. I'm not doing the `IsNumeric` test either, which is a useful step.

Comment: I just used a range of T2:AW2 as I wanted to just test it out on one line before using it on the entire sheet. When I do want to use it on the entire sheet though, I shall be using a `LastRow` and `LastCol` variable as the dataset that I use can differ.

Comment: I believe any error would because of the data-type in the cell not being able to be converted to hex i.e. it is not a decimal. The accepted answer solves this with the `IsNumeric` test so if you wanted to use my code example you should put that test in as well. Equally you could parameterize Han Soloane's code to accept a parameter rather than setting `myRange` in the code.

Comment: It's ok Robin I've fixed it. Turns out I was passing the wrong range. Though I may have to include the numerical check anyway as some of the cells are blanks. Thanks.